# Matlab add selected row data from child table to parent table

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I have in my first figure GUI1 a table and a button that will open a new window with a table GUI2. How is it possible in matalab, to add in the table GUI1 a row data of the selected line in Table 2.

I've try first to select the row number with tihis method:

```
function cellSelect(src,evt)
    index = evt.Indices;
    if any(index)           
        rows = index(:,1);
        set(src,'UserData',rows);
    end
end
```

For

To share data between two window, but I don' know how to use this correctly:

```
b=get(handles.edit2,'String');

setappdata(0,'ReturnText',b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time to try things out, it's always very time consuming for GUI questions, so I just can give you some code lines to play with.

In the first step you need to give every table a tag name:

```
f1  = figure;       %first figure
t1 = uitable(f1);   %first table
set(t1,'Tag','TableOne');
f2  = figure;       %second figure
t2 = uitable(f2);   %second table
set(t2,'Tag','TableTwo');
```

Now you can find your tables in the callback function and access their data:

```
function cellSelect(src,evt) 

index = evt.Indices; %get index of desired row 
row = index(1,1);

t1 = findobj('Tag','TableOne'); 
data1 = get(t1,'Data');
rowdata = data1(row,:);

t2 = findobj('Tag','TableTwo'); 
data2 = get(t2,'Data');
set(t2,'Data',[data2;rowdata]);

end
```

Comment: in my case, each table is in a separate figure. So table1 in Figure 1 and table2 in Figure 2.
I call the Figure 2 from figure1, but how to add a row of a table to another table in another figure?